# Getting NotLeaderForPartitionException for a very long time

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a 3 node kafka cluster, suddenly one of the node in the cluster was down and i started seeing the `NotLeaderForPartitionException` exception in my application logs when sending the message to one of the topics, however for some of the topics i am able post and consume messages.

I could see this problem lasting until all the kafka servers are restarted, after the restart things are all ok.

Now, my question is: why not the new leader not elected for those topics but keep throwing the same `NotLeaderForPartitionException` exception and how to get the new leader election happen for these topics ?

**Exception Trace:**

```
2020-04-11 22:05:21,747 ERROR [pool-15-thread-297] [KafkaMessageProducer:92] Message send failed:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.valueOrError(FutureRecordMetadata.java:94)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:64)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:29)
```

Answer (score 2):

Both Produce and Fetch requests are send to the leader replica of the partition. `NotLeaderForPartitionException` the exception is thrown when the request is sent to the partition which not leader replica of the partition now.

The client maintains the information regarding the leader of each partition as a cache. The complete process of cache management is shown below.

[image]

The client needs to refresh this information by setting the `metadata.max.age.ms` in producer configuration. The default value of this tag is `300000 ms`

You can go through the following Apache Kafka documentation.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/